# IBM Worklight - view embedded pdf and scroll vertically

Tags: ios, html, ipad, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using IBM worklight to create IPad application. I need to display a pdf document in the main application window. I used the following command in the main file (proj.html) inside common folder.

```
<body>
<embed src="http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf" width="400" height="200" alt="pdf" >
</body>
</html>
```

I tried that into Ipad device it works good. However, I try to scroll the pdf up and down I can't. The whole application is dragged down. Is there a way to "fix" the application window so that when I scroll the pdf only the pdf is navigated?

Regards,
S. Yassin

P.S.: I can scroll the pdf down very tough by using two fingers for multi touch

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/291823/186909).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Guys,

I manged to solve it.
After the "build all and deploy" process, the "XCode" project is generated under the folder /ipad/package.

I opened the project using XCode, the I modified the file "Cordova.plist". I found an option named "UiWebViewounce" an has the value "enabled". I changed the value to "disabled".

To summarize, to disable IPad program from bouncing do the following steps

```
1- Using worklight to create XCode project using "Build all and deploy"
2- Open the generated project under ../ipad/package.
3- open the folder Resources/Cordova.plist.
4- Set the option UiWebViewounce to disabled.
```

That's all
Best Wishes,